# Crear una clase "oculta" solo accesible desde otra

Tags: java, clase

Estoy creando una API y me gustaría que el usuario solo dependa de una clase, para que no tenga que buscar a través de varias y sea más sencillo (Para este ejemplo, usaré los nombres ClaseA y ClaseB, ClaseA siendo la pública y ClaseB la que quiero "esconder").

La idea básica la conozco:

```
public class ClaseA extends ClaseB{

    public ClaseA(){

    }
}
```

De esta manera, puedo llamar a todas las funciones de ClaseB también desde ClaseA.

Mi duda es: **Como puedo hacer esta clase "invisible" para el usuario de la API? Quiero decir, como hago que el usuario no pueda utilizar ClaseB? Necesito que, si quiere utilizar una funcion de la ClaseB, lo haga llamando desde ClaseA.**

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Ponla como `Private` en vez de como `Public`

Comment: Lo he intentado antes ya, es lo primero que se me ocurrió a mi también, pero me salta este error: `Illegal modifier for the class ClaseB; only public, abstract & final are permitted`.

Comment: Esto igual te sirve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831791/illegal-modifier-error-for-static-class

Comment: Acabo de ver el post. Sí, eso es (más o menos) lo que yo pretendo hacer, pero en ese caso, mi problema no se resuelve realmente, por que el usuario tendría que usar algo así: `ClaseA.ClaseB c = new ClaseA.ClaseB()`, es decir, que aun necesita utilizar ClaseB. Además, el otro objetivo, que sería tener un código más ordenado (Clases más cortas) tampoco lo cumpliría, por que igualmente tendría la ClaseB dentro de ClaseA. (En el mismo archivo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres es definir un interfaz para tu API, en el interfaz pones la funcionalidad, es como un contrato entre quien usa la interfaz y la implementa:

```
interface miAPI
{
    int hazAlgo();
    int hazOtraCosa(String dato);
}
```

Así la parte pública de tu api sólo devuelve la interfaz, independientemente del objeto que la implemente

```
public static class API
{
    static miAPI getApi()
    {
        //aquí puedes meter la lógica que necesites o usar el patrón de creación que estimes
        return new miImplementacion();
    }
}
```

El uso desde fuera sería por ejemplo:

```
int usarAPI()
    {
        API api = API.getApi();
        return api.hazAlgo() + api.hazOtraCosa("hola");
    }
```

No tienes acceso a la clase que implementa tu API o tu parte de API

Lo que falta es el proveedor del api:

```
public static class API
{
    static miAPI getApi()
    {
        //aquí puedes meter la lógica que necesites o usar el patrón de creación que estimes
        return new miImplementacion();
    }
}
```

y la clase privada que implementa tu API:

```
private static class miImplementacion implements   miAPI
{

    @Override
    public int hazAlgo()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int hazOtraCosa(String dato)
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Este es un ejemplo ilustrativo muy simple. 
Te recomiendo que las interfaces las mantengas afines a su responsabilidad y que hagan solo la parte que conocen, por ejemplo si la interfaz es `Alumno`, que tenga sólo  `asistirAClase` y `hacerExamen`, si necesitas `corregirExamen` debería de ir en otro interfaz `Profesor`
Yo suelo nombrar todas las interfaces con una i delante, así siempre se que son interfaces: iAlumno, iProfesor.

Te recomiendo que leas sobre patrones de diseño: [Patrones de diseño](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)

nota: una clase puede implementar varias interfaces, siguiendo el ejemplo de alumno/profesor con otra forma de ofrecer tu api:

```
public interface iAlumno
{
    String hacerExamen(String examen);
    String asistirAClase(String clase);
}
public interface iProfesor
{
    String crearExamen();
    int corregirExamen();
}


public class ClaseAPI implements iAlumno, iProfesor
{
    private iAlumno alumno;
    private iProfesor profesor;
    ClaseAPI()
    {
        alumno = new Alumno();
        profesor = new Profesor();
    }

    @Override
    public String hacerExamen(String examen)
    {
        return alumno.hacerExamen(examen);
    }

    @Override
    public String asistirAClase(String clase)
    {
        return alumno.asistirAClase(clase);
    }

    @Override
    public String crearExamen()
    {
        return profesor.crearExamen();
    }

    @Override
    public int corregirExamen()
    {
        return profesor.corregirExamen();
    }
}
private class Alumno implements  iAlumno
{

    @Override
    public String hacerExamen(String examen)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String asistirAClase(String clase)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private class Profesor implements iProfesor
{

    @Override
    public String crearExamen()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int corregirExamen()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esto es perfecto, gracias, entonces puedo declarar clases privadas que implementen una interfaz publica y así "obligar" al usuario a usar la API, cierto? Es genial, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que sea de utilidad, no dejes de mirar los patrones de diseño que te será de utilidad.

Comment: Por supuesto. Todo lo que sea aprender será bienvenido.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes poner la visibilidad de la clase padre a sólo el package, quitando todos los modificadores de visibilidad (class A). Las clases hijas tendrían que estar en el mismo package como públicas (public class B).

```
class A {
    ...
}

public class B extends A {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class B {
    protected B(){
    //constructor
    }
    protected void method(){
       //Cuerpo
    }
}
```

en el mismo package..

```
  public class A extends B{
     public void methodPublico(){
        super.method();
    }
  }
```

Comment: buenas!, puedes explicar un poco más tu respuesta?

Comment: Suponte que distribuyes tu libreria/software en un package (jar). De acuerdo a la visibilidad y el control de acceso (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html en ingles) dejar la clase en protected permite que la clase B sea visible dentro del package, por la subclase (ademas de la clase en si) pero no por el resto del mundo, por lo que la clase B quedaria invisible fuera de su package y la clase A seria la interaccion directa

Comment: gracias @3d0, excelente explicación.

Answer (score 1):

Ocultar la clase no Este sería un ejemplo, defines una clase  tienes una `ClaseA` que hereda de una `ClaseB`, la `ClaseB` es definida como abstract para que no se pueda instanciar (no se pueda crear un objeto del tipo `ClaseB`).

Dentro de `ClaseB` definimos un método privado, el cual  solo puede ser accesible por `ClaseB`.

Como ejemplo, se crea una instancia de `ClaseA` pero el método que puede ser accesible es únicamente el de `ClaseA` y no el de `ClaseB` de la cual heredamos:

```
abstract class ClaseB{        

    public ClaseB() {    
        System.out.println("ClassB");
    }

   private void realizaTarea() {
        System.out.println("realizaTarea() de Clase B");
    }
}

class ClaseA extends ClaseB {    
       public ClaseA() {
          System.out.println("ClassA");
    }    
     public void realizaTarea() {
        System.out.println("realizaTarea() de Clase A");
    }
}

public class JavaApplication1 {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Se instancia ClaseA que hereda de ClaseB.
     ClaseA a = new ClaseA();
       //El método que puede ser accesible es el de ClaseA y no de ClaseB.
       a.realizaTarea();
     }             

}
```

El anterior ejemplo tendrá como salida:

```
ClassB
ClassA
realizaTarea() de Clase A
```

Comment: Muy interesante, no se me había ocurrido usar Abstract, si quisiera que ClaseA extendiera de varias clases (Imaginemos ClaseB, ClaseC y ClaseD), tendría que hacer que ClaseB extendiera ClaseC y ClaseC extendiera ClaseD, verdad? Quiero decir, no podría hacer que ClaseA extienda a todas directamente, cierto?